# Error formatting monetary value - Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Friends, I have an input to enter the price of a product. I use a mask to format the value, but only the number is saved in the database. Without any characters.

**12345**, **123456**.

I'm trying to format this in php using number_format(). I've tried money_format(), but it always returns an error.

The two exits would be: **123,45** and **1.234,56**

I'm using:

```
<?= number_format($product->price, 0, ",", "."); ?>
```

But then he returns:**12.345** and **123.456**

I appreciate if anyone can analyze. Any comments are welcome.

The price field is varchar, but I've also tried double and float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are starting from a varchar that will be evaluated as an integer because it has no "." in it and the last 2 numbers are your decimals (cents).

So, first of all divide the integer by 100, then apply number format:

```php
number_format($product->price / 100, 0, ",", ".");
```

Comment: Thank you. I decided this way:number_format($product->price / 100, 2, ",", ".");